# Capturing output with newline characters from ruby stdout in bash script

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, quoting

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

output=$(ruby <<-EORUBY
  5.times { puts "foo" }
EORUBY
)

echo $output
```

In the example from above I get:

```
foo foo foo foo foo
```

How to prevent from trimming off newline character after each foo?
Basically, I would like to get:

```
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use double quotes:

```
echo "$output"
```